# After upgrading xubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, chrome resets the xprintidle idle timer every 20-30 seconds, How to stop it?

Tags: google-chrome, xorg, xubuntu

I have a bunch of scripts that do things based on extended idle times of the machine.
Everything worked great until I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04.

The upgrade of course had problems, but after I worked it all out, the only weird thing I'm left with is that my scripts based on the xprintidle time don't work. Watching it go, I notice that the idle timer resets every 20 seconds or sometimes 30 seconds, like clockwork.

After some playing around I found if I close chrome, it doesn't reset until I actually move the mouse or click a button.

So it's something about either a newer version of chrome or how it reacts to X.

Any ideas how to turn off whatever's going on?

Answer (score 0):

it turned out not to be chrome, but... the chase.com webpage.
I don't know what or how it's doing it, but if I have a tab in chrome that has a chase.com page up, my printidle resets every 20 seconds.